# Write database into xml file

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, xmlwriter

1. How can I export the database into a .xml file with the format utf-8 because I have the format utf-8 BOM but I need it without the BOM

The code for creating my xml file is:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName, settings))
    {
        dt.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
        xmlWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

2. In the first line of my created .xml, the format is written as "utf-8" but I need it without the "-", I just need "utf8"

[image: this is the created .xml file (the left side is how it should be and the right side is my created xml file]

3. In the first line, how can I change `DocumentElement` into `table name = "UnknownTable"`?

Comment: Your question is too broad, you should narrow it down to 1 question that includes what you have tried/researched so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("UnknownTable");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ticket-id", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11528, 4917 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11529, 4918 });


            string identification =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf8\"?>" +
                "<table name=\"UnknownTable\">" +
                "</table>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(identification);
            XElement table = doc.Root;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement newRow = new XElement("row");
                table.Add(newRow);
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < dt.Columns.Count; colNum++)
                {
                    string name = dt.Columns[colNum].ColumnName;
                    newRow.Add(new XElement(name, row[colNum]));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

1.
To create encoding without BOM use:

```
new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false);
```

2.
According to the standard must be utf-8, with hyphen.

3.
Specify the name of the DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("UnknownTable");
```

or

```
dt.TableName = "UnknownTable";
```